# What is the time complexity of this algorithm(code)?

Tags: java, algorithm, computer-science

I have algorithm that translate six types of XPath queries into SQL queries. so, my code contains If-elseif-else statement (multiple if). I read from the internet that the time complexity of the If-elseif-else statement is the worst-case time of one one of the if that has more processing. I need to know what is is the time complexity for this code:

```
} else if (Query_Type == 5){
for (int i = strXPathQuery.length()-1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (strXPathQuery.charAt(i) == '/') {
             position = i;
             break;
        }    
 }   // end for loop                              
 Last_Node = strXPathQuery.substring(position+1);
 strAncestor_Path = ""; 
 int bracket_pos=0;
 for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
   if (strXPathQuery.charAt(i) == '[') {
          bracket_pos = i;
          break;
  } else if (strXPathQuery.charAt(i) == '/' && strXPathQuery.charAt(i+1) == '/')  {
           strAncestor_Path = strAncestor_Path + "%";
  }
  else {
            strAncestor_Path = strAncestor_Path + strXPathQuery.charAt(i);
  }  // end if statement
 }   // end for
    int operator_pos = 0; 
    String Node_condition=""; 
    for (int i = bracket_pos+1; i < position-2; i++) {
      if ((strXPathQuery.charAt(i) == '<') || (strXPathQuery.charAt(i) ==  '>') || (strXPathQuery.charAt(i) == '=') || (strXPathQuery.charAt(i) == '!')) {
              operator_pos = i;
              break;
                }
        else {
            Node_condition = Node_condition + strXPathQuery.charAt(i);
        }   // end if            }  
    String Value_condition=""; 
    for (int i = operator_pos; i < position-1; i++) {
        Value_condition = Value_condition + strXPathQuery.charAt(i);
    }  // end for loop 
    strSQLQuery = "SELECT L2.Node_Value \n" +
                  "FROM Leaf_Node L1, Leaf_Node L2, Ancestor_Path P\n" +
                  "WHERE P.Ances_PathExp LIKE '" + strAncestor_Path + "'\n" +
                  "AND L1.Ances_PathID = P.Ances_PathID \n" +
                  "AND L1.Node_Name = '" + Node_condition + "'\n" +
                  "AND L1.Node_Value '".replace("'", "") + Value_condition + "'\n".replace("'", "") +
                  "AND L2.Node_Name = '" + Last_Node + "'\n" +
                  "AND L1.Ances_PathID = L2.Ances_PathID \n" +
                  "AND L1.Ances_Pos = L2.Ances_Pos " ;
    txtSQLQuery.setText(strSQLQuery);
        }
        }
```

Comment: What's stopping you from calculating it? Or is it just easier to have someone else trudge through your code?

Answer (score -1):

You have three looks there that could be `O(N^2)`.   For example.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
      ...
      strAncestor_Path = strAncestor_Path + strXPathQuery.charAt(i);
      ...
 }
```

Assume (worst case) that for that loop, the value of `position` is `strXPathQuery.length()` ... or `N`.  That means that you are appending a character to the same string `N` times.  Since appending a character to a string is an `O(N)` operation.  (The append is creating a new string, copying all characters in the existing string.)  The complexity of doing that `N` times is `O(N^2)`.

The average complexity *could* be better than that, but it will depend on the input.

<sup>(And I don't have the patience to get my head around what you are actually trying to here.  The your code's crap style is making my eyes hurt.)</sup>

---

If you want to perform the performance, don't build strings like that.  Use a `StringBuilder`.

```
 StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();

 for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
      ...
      path.append(strXPathQuery.charAt(i));
      ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. This code handle one input condition but there are another 5 input conditions. My question is what is the time complexity for code having if-elseif-statement. I display here the part of if-elseif-statement which has more operations than other. So, we can calculate the time complexity of the algorithm based on this code. Are you sure that the time complexity is O (n^2)

Comment: I am sure that worst case is `O(N^2)`.  In the best case it is `O(N)`.  On average ... it depends on the input.